# Добавление полей в GridView

Tags: yii2

есть такой  код

```
if(is_array($color)){$colorDatas=ArrayHelper::map($color,'id','value');}
```

теперь мне надо в случае если $colorDatas не пустое мне надо добавить следующий виджет в 'columns'

```
[
                'filter'    =>Select2::widget ([
                    'model'         =>  $searchModel,
                    'attribute'     =>  'color',
                    'data'          => $colorDatas,
                    'language'  => 'ru',
                    'options'   => ['multiple' => true,'placeholder' => Yii::t('backend','SELECT_SHOP')],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'allowClear' => true
                    ],
                ]),
                'attribute'   => 'color',
                'value'       =>    function($model){
                    return $model->theGetValue($model);
                }
            ],
```

в  GridView не подскажите как этосделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Формируйте предварительно список колонок, в чем проблема?

```
$columns = [
   // all columns from GridView::widget execution without colors
];

if ($colorDatas) {
    $columns[] = ['filter' => Select2::widget /* all code for column */]
}

GridView::widget([
    // your settings
    'columns' => $columns
]);
```